# Parent child data sharing best way in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In Angular 2 I have a situation where a Component can have many child component and only one component will be shown at a time by using *ngIf like this.

```
<div class="main-content" *ngIf="vdcService.vdRequest.sectionId == 1">
   <a></a>
</div>

<div class="main-content" *ngIf="vdcService.vdRequest.sectionId == 15">
    <b></b>
</div>
<div class="main-content" *ngIf="vdcService.vdRequest.sectionId == 15">
    <c></c>
</div>
```

and many more and all these components will show their specific data in table and other elements. Now I want to send data to these child components from parent. How can I do this in best way means should I pass the data by using **@Input** or should I store the data in service and child components directly access the data from service. Parent component is fetching the data from rest service by looking which component is going to render. I need some suggestion which option should I use or any other best solution?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Yes I read that but let suppose I have an object define in service then every child component can access it then why I send it to child every time.

Comment: It depends on your detailed requirements. If you use an observable, your components can get notified about changes, otherwise the components need to poll for changes (Angular change detection does this for you) which is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a parent to children communication. The simplest way is to use @Input on each of the child components. The parent component have just to update the value tied to these input every time a data is fetched from the rest service.